# Patterns to manage database relationships in memory

Tags: c#, design-patterns

[A while ago](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104752/framework-to-track-changes-and-relationships-in-c), I wrote a small framework in C# to manage database relationships (1 to 1, 1 to N) in memory. I've since refactored some of the design and here's an example of the how one might use the current code:

```
class A : FrameworkEntity
{
    public static readonly Relationship1To1<A, B> relationship
        = RelationshipManager.Instance.Relate1To1<A, B>();

    public B B
    {
        get { return relationship.GetForward(this); }
        set { relationship.SetForward(this, value); }
    }

    public C Parent
    {
        get { return C.relationship.GetReverse(this); }
    }
}

class B : FrameworkEntity
{
    public A A
    {
        get { return A.relationship.GetReverse(this); }
        set { A.relationship.SetReverse(value, this); }
    }
}

class C : FrameworkEntity
{
    public static readonly Relationship1ToN<C, A> relationship
        = RelationshipManager.Instance.Relate1ToN<C, A>();

    // the implementation will call the RelationshipManager
    // to update the relationship on add/update/delete
    public ICollection<A> Children
    {
        get { return relationship.GetFoward(this); }
    }
}
```

To me, this seems like a use of the [mediator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) with [dependency properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752914(v=vs.100).aspx). There's a central singleton object, the `RelationshipManager`, that's used to manage changes to an object's relatives. That static dependency is accessed by each instance through instance properties.

Is there another way to do this, without using dependency properties? I didn't design the original code for this framework, and am curious how else someone might do this.

Comment: If you're looking for design patterns - Martin Fowler has a set of patterns related to relation data structures especially manage dependent tables etc, see "Object-Relational Structural Patterns" http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/

Answer (score 0):

[Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/) apparently -has- a C# wrapper, but it [does look to be maintained](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki). Making a Sqlite DB in memory seems to be ideal for this (depending on the complexity of the work you are trying to do to make 'queries', 'joins', etc.) And it has a tiny footprint.

(This might be above/beyond what you want to do, but it might be worth it to actually get real Query/Join support, etc)